# How to get a *.gsheet file on a network drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

First of all, I'm not a programmer or IT manager, I work in a social non-profit organization (local, small) but I'm the one who gets (tries) to sort things out when it turns to IT related issues.

Recently, we decided to move our shared folders from Google Drive to a local server. Not much of a change... We had xls and gsheet files, which were copied to the new drive and work just about the same. We still use google accounts for emails, and shared google files for collaborative, simultaneous work.

Now the problem is when a team member creates a new gsheet file. Ideally, we'd like the .gsheet file to appear in the network drive's directory structure. But there's no way to export the file in this format directly from the google sheet interface.

Things I've tried :
I edited the content of the .gsheet file in notepad and it looks pretty simple (file ID, owner...). I could generate the file "manually" but my colleagues wouldn't like this option.
Other option is to have Backup and Synch running and get the gsheet file from there, but computers are not assigned to a specific team member so they would have to re-log into the synch app as well.
I tried to understand how the google API "files: export" works, but it's too complicated for me.

In short, is there a simple way to generate a .gsheet file so it can be accessed from a network drive ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The only solution that came to my mind is to create a txt file based a gdoc/gsheet file content, let people fill the blanks and then save under gdoc/gsheet format : {"url": "https://docs.google.com/open?id=COPY FILE ID HERE", "doc_id": "COPY FILE ID HERE", "email": "YOUR EMAIL HERE"}.... But's that's pretty prehistorical

Comment: Oh actually you don't need more than the "url", the rest is optional. Prehistorical but fast...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*.gsheet` file extension is created automatically and it essentially represents the shortcut of the spreadsheet from the Drive.

So even if you make use of Drive's `files.export` request, it won't solve your problem as the request exports a Google file to the requested MIME type and returns the exported content.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-files#types):

> You cannot upload or download folders, shortcuts, third-party shortcuts, and Google Workspace documents to or from Google Drive. However, you can upload or export Google Workspace documents if they use compatible formats. For example, you can create a Google Doc when you import a PDF. Similarly, you can export a Google Slides presentation as a `.pptx` file.

Therefore, since the extension that you want corresponds to a Google Sheet, the only solution is to have all the files needed in a [shared drive](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025) and have the Sync enabled.

#### Reference

- [Drive API File Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-files#types);
- [Shared Drives](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025).

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like the best option : 1 shared drive containing all the *.gsheet and *.gdoc shared by team members. Then we can copy the shortcut and put it in the relevant network drive.

Comment: Thank you for the update! If this was of help to you, would you mind marking the answer as "accepted" for documentation purpose?

Comment: Sorry I was searching for something to click on but couldn't find it...